# How to iterate through subfolders and convert files into csv while saving them in that subfolder

Tags: python, csv, path, iteration, subdirectory

I have a folder and subdirectories which have txt files in it. I want to convert each txt file to csv and save the files with the same name as txt file but in csv format. For instance, I have a folder called A and A has

- subfolder B (B has subfolders as C,D,etc.). Each subfolder has a file in it with different names such as test1.txt, test112.json, etc.
- subfolder E (E has subfolders as F,K,etc.). Each subfolder has a file in it with different names such as sub folder F has testF.txt, testFgf.json, etc. in it, sub folder K has testKk.txt.

I would like to convert each .txt file into .csv for each sub folder and have the same file name as:

- subfolder B (B has subfolders as C,D,etc.). Each subfolder has a file in it with different names such as test1.txt, test1.json, **test1.csv**.
- subfolder E (E has subfolders as F,K,etc.). Each subfolder has a file in it with different names such as sub folder F has testF.txt, testF.json, **testF.csv** , sub folder K has testKk.txt, **testKk.csv**.
  I have tried:

```
root="C:/user/main_folder/A/"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
         if filepath.endswith(".txt"):
            print(os.path.join(path, name))
            file=task_info
            task_info.to_csv(path.join(filepath, file_name), index=False)
```

In here, I can get the right file path from each sub folders but I cannot convert them into csv and save them in the right folder with the right names.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is happening with your attempt? is it generating any error? if so, please consider putting that error in the question. in the final line of your code, you've left off `os.` from what was supposed to be `os.path.join()`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : editing the files

you can use recursion

```
root="C:/user/main_folder/A"

def explore_and_execute(initial_path):
    for item in os.listdir(initial_path):
        item_fullpath = initial_path+"/"+item
        if os.path.isdir(item):
            explore_and_execute(item_fullpath)
        if os.path.isfile(item):
            if item.endswith(".txt"):
                edit_file(filepath)
                os.rename(item_fullpath, item_fullpath[:-4]+".csv")


def edit_file(filepath):
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        original_data = f.read()

    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        # put your edit scenario here
        ...
    

explore_and_execute(root)
```

here you will be looping until the end of the directory branch

Comment: `os.walk()` has recursion built-in. why roll your own here?

Comment: this one works. why not? lets be objective

Comment: Thanks but I would like to ask if I want to edit the file and then save then how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

With the path to the file you will need to use:

```
root="C:/user/main_folder/A/"
path, subdirs, files next(os.walk(root))
for ele in subdirs:
    _, _, file next(os.walk(root+ele)
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + ele + os.sep
            if name.endswith(".txt"):
               new_name = name.split('.')[0] 
               os.rename(filepath+name, filepath+new_name+'.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your code doesn't go through the all sub directories to get all the needed files. Secondly, I think there is a mistake in your def store function in with open() line. Overall, when I try this code it gives an error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filepath'.

Comment: Yeah, the error is that I was using filepath as a string instead of using the value stored in the variable filepath.

Comment: Thanks. However, I think the issue is with the filepath=root + os.sep+ name since it doesnt go through right sub directories.

Comment: Well, that 1 just goes to the root path files, for subdirectories you will need another loop over subdirs adding the subdir name to the filepath. I will update the code.

Comment: Thanks again, I think instead of filepath = root + os.sep + name we could have written filepath = path + os.sep + name and it could go through the next levels. However, even if we fix this either your new way or by changing it as I mentioned, there is an issue with the store function as it gives TypeError: write() argument must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: I found that `os.rename()` function. Maybe its better this way.

Comment: Actually I need to modify the file as well and then save. On the other hand, os.rename() works well.